# Android Mapv2 Issue

Tags: android, google-maps, maps

All,
Trying to use google v2 map api in my android application and can't get it to work, it keeps displaying a blank white page!
I even tried running samples from https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/MapsV2 and got the BasicMap application compiled and installed on my device but exactly same issue!
Since this is happening both for my code and this code that all I heard is a valid source I assume this is not the Key issue as these two use two different keys.
I've done all I could, here is manifest file from the sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.commonsware.android.mapsv2.basic"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16"/>

    <permission
        android:name="com.commonsware.android.mapsv2.basic.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_DEBUG_APP" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">

        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

        <activity
            android:name="MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyC4iyT46cB00IdKGcy5EmAxK5uCOQX2Oy8"/>

        <activity android:name="LegalNoticesActivity">
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Any idea what this could be?

Comment: try with creating new api key

Comment: Can you include your MainActivity code please?

Comment: Post your activity code if possible .

Comment: You can see the code in the link I have in the question, in my case I have no code really in my activity and this is simply initializing the google map object that is not happening. I will add a new Key and give it a try to see if this works.

Comment: I did create a new key and exactly the same behaviour!

Answer (score 1):

Try to follow the following guide I wrote for adding a Google Map Api V2:

[Google Map API V2](https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435)

and please share you logcat stack trace with us so we could understand more clearly what is your problem.